# Dúvida pra automatizar função em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou utilizando uma função em Javascript pra mostrar/ocultar uma `div` de acordo com a escolha de um `radio`, mas agora eles se tornaram muitos, então estou tentando automatizar isso da forma que estou aprendendo no codeacademy.

À partir do código que já utilizava, criei uma variável como função, e atribui dois parâmetros, um pra cada `id` (do `radio`, que deve estar checado, e da `div`, que deve aparecer). Depois coloquei no HTML da mesma forma que vinha usando (dentro do `onclick`), mas não está funcionando.

Assim é como estou tentando:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/kxt2fkym/1/).

JS:

```
var esconderradio = function(var1, var2) {

    if (document.getElementById(var1).checked) {
        document.getElementById(var2).style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(var2).style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Daí no HTML coloquei assim:

```
<label class="radio" for="Csaldsim">
    Sim
    <input type="radio" id="Csaldsim" onclick="esconderradio('Csaldim', 'salvenc')"></label>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldnao">
    Não
    <input type="radio" id="Csaldnao" onclick="onclick="esconderradio('Csaldim', 'salvenc')"></label>
```

E assim é o código que estou utilizando (adaptei 2 casos pra mostrar como estou fazendo, mas já são 33):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/o3dd527j/1/).

```js
    function HabCampos33() {
        if (document.getElementById('Csaldsim').checked) {
            document.getElementById('salvenc').style.display = "";
        }  else {
            document.getElementById('salvenc').style.display = "none";
        }
    }


    function HabCampos32() {
        if (document.getElementById('Csaldsim2').checked) {
            document.getElementById('salvenc2').style.display = "";
        }  else {
            document.getElementById('salvenc2').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<label class="radio" for="Csaldsim">
    Sim
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldsim" onclick="HabCampos33()"></label>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldnao">
    Não
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldnao" onclick="HabCampos33()"></label>

<br>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldsim2">
    Sim
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldsim2" onclick="HabCampos32()"></label>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldnao2">
    Não
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldnao2" onclick="HabCampos32()"></label>

<br>

<div  class=" col-md-3 panel panel-default" id="salvenc" style="display:none;">
    <label class="btn" for="Csalvenc">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Tsalvenc" id="Csalvenc"></label>
</div>
<br>
<div  class=" col-md-3 panel panel-default" id="salvenc2" style="display:none;">
    <label class="btn" for="Csalvenc">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Tsalvenc" id="Csalvenc2"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu alterei sua função, da uma olhada:

```js
function manipulaDiv(checked, idDiv) {
    if (checked) {
        document.getElementById(idDiv).style.display = "";
    }  else {
        document.getElementById(idDiv).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<label class="radio" for="Csaldsim">
    Sim
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldsim" onclick="manipulaDiv(true, 'salvenc')"></label>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldnao">
    Não
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldnao" onclick="manipulaDiv(false, 'salvenc')"></label>

<br>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldsim2">
    Sim
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldsim2" onclick="manipulaDiv(true, 'salvenc2')"></label>
<label class="radio" for="Csaldnao2">
    Não
    <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="Tsald" id="Csaldnao2" onclick="manipulaDiv(false, 'salvenc2')"></label>

<br>
<br>

<div  class=" col-md-3 panel panel-default" id="salvenc" style="display:none;">
    <label class="btn" for="Csalvenc">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Tsalvenc" id="Csalvenc"></label>
</div>
<br>
<div  class=" col-md-3 panel panel-default" id="salvenc2" style="display:none;">
    <label class="btn" for="Csalvenc">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Tsalvenc" id="Csalvenc2"></label>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Legal! Quando vc faz `if (checked)` é como se fizesse `if (checked === true)` né, muito bom! Vai me poupar muitas linhas :-). Valeu!

Comment: Exatamente, a operação `if` espera um retorno booleano então se você já tem uma variável booleana pode passar direto :)

Comment: O `if` do javascript tem outras particularidades, mas acho que não vem ao caso agora.

Comment: Fiquei curioso, você está falando [deste tipo de particularidade](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13801481/825789)?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, justamente por causa dessa propriedade de qualquer objeto retornar um valor `true` também conseguimos verificar se o valor é `null/undefined/vazio` sem nem precisar fazer comparações dentro da expressão.